# Yii2 - i18n for the {attribute} in js validation messages

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yii2

After changing the default language, the js validation messages are also changed to the target language. 
However the attribute names are still in English, e.g. {attribute}(in English) XXXXXXXX(in target language).
My question is: how can I translate those attribute names to the target language as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is special method in model called [attributeLabels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#attributeLabels%28%29-detail) for these purposes. It returns the array where keys are original attribute names and values - according labels. You should fill this manually in dependence of used language and desired output.

Example for russian language:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'city_id' => 'Город',
    ];
}
```

You can use [i18n](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html) here as well:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'city_id' => \Yii::t('app', 'City');,
    ];
}
```

Default validation uses this labels for displaying errors.